# Trouble in the for loop while printing the list

Tags: python, list

Here I'm trying to use a for loop in list's, but whenever I'm using range with for loop, I'm getting this error

```
for i in range(listType):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
 
KeyboardInterrupt
```

But when I'm trying len() function with the range in for loop , there's no error. Can anyone explain me ,like what's happening here?

Here's the piece of code I'm trying to run-

```
listType = ['US', 'UK', 'India', 'China']
for i in range(listType):
    print(listType[i])
```

Comment: You need `for i in range(len(listType)):`

Comment: Better would be to do `for i in listType: print(i)` or `print(*listType, sep='\n')`

Comment: Yeah,i know this but why am I SUPPOSED to use len() function?

Comment: You don't need `range` at all. `for i in listType: print(i)`.

Comment: `range` *only* produces sequences of integers; it doesn't know anything about lists. `len(listType)` provides an integer related to the length of the list which `range` can use.

Comment: `range` counts from 0 to whatever number you give it. `len` gives the size of the list as a number. You're not *supposed* to do anything particular, that's just a way you can use those functions together to do the thing you want.

Comment: I know that but i'm trying this piece of code in some other way, so that's why i'd like to know , why len() function is used with this range in the for loop

Comment: Ahh, now it's clear , thanks now i got this.

Comment: "I'm trying this piece of code in some other way". You might want to ask about *that* .

Comment: @UzumakiPanda, if an answer worked for you, you should accept it to mark it as a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `range()` function accepts an integer input. So since `listType` is a `list` it throws an error because "'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer."

`range(n)` wants to create a `range` object from `0` to `n` but it cannot if `n` is not a type that can be within a range (integer). `len()` however, returns an integer that is equal to the length of the list, therefore `range()` is happy with the integer input.

It would be simpler to instead use this:

```
listType = ['US', 'UK', 'India', 'China']
for i in listType:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
US
UK
India
China
```

Comment: Actually I could had wrote that piece of code without using range and len() function but i was just curious why am i supposed to use len() function with range

Comment: @UzumakiPanda see my updated explanation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Python's `for` loops are like JavaScript's `forEach` loops:

```
for i in listType:
    print(i)
```

The `range` constructor you put in your code is often used to simulate a pure `for` loop in Python:

```
for i in range(len(listType)):
    print(listType[i]) # This produces the same output
```

In Python `range` is an iterable class, its constructor works like this:

```
range(start, end)
for i in range(1, 4):
    print(i) # 1 - 2 - 3
```

Anyway it takes two `int` arguments (there are three arguments, but only one is compulsory), so you can't pass an `iterable` (in your case a `list`) as the first positional argument of `range`.

---

When you want to iterate over an iterable, it's a better practice to use the first code I provided.

When you need to access the `index` during the iteration, it's a better practice to do like this:

```
for index, element in enumerate(listType):
    print(f"{element} at index {index}")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `len()` to do this:

```py
listType = ['US', 'UK', 'India', 'China']
for i in range(len(list Type)):
    print(listType[i])
```

Or using a more easy way:

```py
listType = ['US', 'UK', 'India', 'China']
for i in listType:
    print(i)
```